# restrict back with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation in my react native app. When switching to another screen I am using this command this.props.navigation.navigate

ex. `this.props.navigation.navigate('AddGradeLevelScreen')`

its been working pretty well but how can restrict going back to the past screen(the back button of the phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the route state and initialising it with the 'AddGradeLevelScreen',

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AddGradeLevelScreen'})
  ]
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```